# Django ModelChoiceField has no plus button

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm making a Django app with custom users. I've outlined the key components of my problem below, missing code is denoted by '...'. My custom user model has a foreign key relationship as follows:

```
class MyCustomUser(models.AbstractBaseUser, models.PermissionsMixin)
    ...
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)

class Location(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

I've written a custom user form that includes this field as follows:

```
class MyCustomUserCreationForm(models.ModelForm)
    ...
    location = forms.ModelChoiceField(Location.objects.all())
```

This all appears to be working correctly, however, there is no plus button to the right of the select field for location. I want to be able to add a location when I create a user, in the same way that you can add polls when creating choices in the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial02/#adding-related-objects). According [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216702/disabling-only-specific-green-plus-icons-on-auto-generated-forms), I might not see the green plus if I don't have permission to change the model, but I am logged in as a superuser with all permissions. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to set a `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper` wrapper in your model form:

> The RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper (found in django.contrib.admin.widgets)
>   is used in the Admin pages to include the capability on a Foreign Key
>   control to add a new related record. (In English: puts the little green plus sign to the right of the control.)

```
class MyCustomUserCreationForm(models.ModelForm)
    ...
    location = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Location.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyCustomUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        rel = ManyToOneRel(self.instance.location.model, 'id') 
        self.fields['location'].widget = RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(self.fields['location'].widget, rel, self.admin_site)
```

I could make a mistake in the example code, so see these posts and examples:

- [RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper](http://dashdrum.com/blog/2012/07/relatedfieldwidgetwrapper/)
- [More RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper – My Very Own Popup](http://dashdrum.com/blog/2012/12/more-relatedfieldwidgetwrapper-the-popup/)
- [Django admin - How can I add the green plus sign for Many-to-many Field in custom admin form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692822/django-admin-how-can-i-add-the-green-plus-sign-for-many-to-many-field-in-custo)
- [How can I manually use RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper around a custom widget?](https://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/5950235765d8e46a/c21bed1e9bdeab57?show_docid=c21bed1e9bdeab57)
- [Django: override RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156028/django-override-relatedfieldwidgetwrapper)

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction, thanks for all the links.  I used your code but I had to modify it a little. I had to add a couple of lines to the ModelAdmin to pass the admin site to the form, and define the rel as `MyCustomUser._meta.get_fields('location').rel`

Comment: @EmeraldOwl: Minor Typo -- `MyCustomUser._meta.get_field('location').rel`.

Comment: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'rel' when i use yCustomUser._meta.get_field('my_field').rel

Comment: I am using Django 3 and "rel" property is not defined in the return type of get field method, change "remote_field" property instead "rel"

Comment: can you help with this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69289560/how-to-add-button-for-foreign-key-similar-to-djangos-admin

Answer (score 8):

I have created method based on the answers above:

```
def add_related_field_wrapper(form, col_name):
    rel_model = form.Meta.model
    rel = rel_model._meta.get_field(col_name).rel
    form.fields[col_name].widget = 
    RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(form.fields[col_name].widget, rel, 
    admin.site, can_add_related=True, can_change_related=True)
```

And then calling this method from my form:

```
class FeatureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    offer = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Offer.objects.all(), required=False)
    package = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Package.objects.all(), required=False)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FeatureForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        add_related_field_wrapper(self, 'offer')
        add_related_field_wrapper(self, 'package')
```

That works fine on Django 1.8.2.

Comment: I have to add `class Meta\n\tmodel = ModeName\n\tfields = ('offer', 'package')`

Comment: This is a pretty neat solution. I needed to use the `remote_field` property instead of `rel`.

Additionally, to make the adding page open in a popup, like in Django Admin, some of Django Admin's Javascript is required. Adding the Media subclass as followed to the form class and `{{ form.media }}` in the template seemed to do the trick.

Sorry for the lack of line breaks: `class CarForm(forms.ModelForm): ... class Media: ... js = ("admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js", "admin/js/jquery.init.js", "admin/js/core.js", "admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js",)`

Answer (score 2):

Google pointed me to this page when searching how to get a "+" icon next to fields in a custom form with ForeignKey relationship, so I thought I'd add.

For me, using `django-autocomplete-light` did the trick very well, using the "add another" functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to go that far, and besides, these answers are probably outdated as NONE of them worked for me in any capacity.

What I did to solve this is, as long as you have the ForeignKey field already in your model, then you can just create your custom ModelChoiceField:

```
class LocationModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "%" % (obj.name)
```

The key next is **NOT** to create a custom field for the ModelChoiceField in your ModelForm (ie *location = forms.ModelChoiceField(Location.objects.all())*)

In other words, leave that out and in your ModelForm have something like this:

```
class UserAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

Lastly, in your ModelAdmin:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = User
    form = UserAdminForm

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'location':
        return LocationModelChoiceField(queryset=Location.objects.order_by('name')) # if you want to alphabetize your query
    return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Method : Using **.remote_field** instead of rel

```
def add_related_field_wrapper(self,form, col_name):
    rel_model = form.Meta.model
    rel = rel_model._meta.get_field(col_name).remote_field
    form.fields[col_name].widget = RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(form.fields[col_name].widget, rel, admin.site, can_add_related=True, can_change_related=True)


def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomerAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.add_related_field_wrapper(self, 'offer')
    self.add_related_field_wrapper(self, 'package')
```

Thankyou,